# Can I use tidyverse to make a for loop with an 'if' and 'else' statement faster

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a for loop using an if else statement for data mining. However it takes a really long time to run. I read somewhere that tidyverse (dplyr, or purrr) can sometimes be a faster substitute opposed to running loops but I can't find any 'if' 'else' functions in purrr. Here is my loop so far:

```
  for (j in 1:length(my.query$data$value)){
    if(my.query$data$station[j] %in%  dataPRCP[,1]){
      rowNum<-which(dataPRCP[,1]==my.query$data$station[j])
      dataPRCP[rowNum,i+3]<-my.query$data$value[j]
    } else {
      dataPRCP<-rbind(dataPRCP,emptyrow)
      rowNum<-length(dataPRCP[,1])
      location <- ncdc_stations(stationid = my.query$data$station[j])
      dataPRCP[rowNum,1]<-my.query$data$station[j]
      dataPRCP[rowNum,2]<-location$data$latitude
      dataPRCP[rowNum,3]<-location$data$longitude
      dataPRCP[rowNum,i+3]<-my.query$data$value[j]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a minimal working example in order for direct help (I have no idea what your data looks like, nor how you are trying to manipulate it).  However, the general strategy in `purrr` is to apply a function to each element in a list.  Put your if/else statement in a function (with suitable inputs), and `map` applies the function to each element:

```
# trivial example
library(purrr)
result <- map(1:5, print)
```

or (with if/else)

```
f <- function(x) {
  if(x > 2) data_frame(a = 4, b = 10)
  else data_frame(a = 0, b = 3)
}
map_df(1:5, f) # result is a data_frame
```

If you're output is a new element in a data frame, you might find it more useful to check out `ifelse`, which is vectorized or the `tidyverse` version `if_else` which is more picky about data types.

```
# trivial example
# library(dplyr)
data_frame(a = 1:4) %>%
  mutate(b = if_else(a > 2, 1, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all i needed! @Melissa_Key